# Discrete Math - Discrete Relations, divisibility, remainder

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Prove that, for all $ \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x + p$ and $(x + p)(x − p)$ leave the same remainder when divided by $2$.

∈ = belong

Z = set of the integers

p = 3

My tentative approach is given below:

$x = y \ ( \text{mod } 2)$

$x + 3 = y \ ( \text{mod } 2)$

$x = 2(x + 3) + y$

$x_1 = y \ ( \text{mod } 2)$

$(x + 3) (x + 3) = y \ ( \text{mod } 2)$

$x_1 = 2[(x + 3) (x - 3)] + y$

$x_1 = 2[x² - 3x + 3x - 9] + y$

Can someone help me with this problem? I can't solve it. Thanks!!

Comment: It isn't clear what you have attempted. It would be helpful if you write more explicitly defining each term.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $x$ is even then $x+3$ is odd, and so is $x^2-9$, and a similar argument works for $x$ odd.  But $x\equiv y\bmod2$ and $x+3\equiv y\bmod2$ are contradictory

Comment: FYI: The English translation for "rest" to use here is "remainder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case x + p is even.  Clearly (x + p)(x - p) is even
Case x + p is odd.
Assume x - p is even.  Then 2x = x + p + x - p is odd.
Thus x - p is odd and accordingly (x + p)(x - p) is odd.